# java 1.6 enum issue com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Style.WRAPPED

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, rational-rsa

I am migrating my application from Java 1.4 to Java 1.6 and RSA 7.0 to RSA 8.0
When I am opening my projects which used to be in RSA 7.0, some of the files which are generated from WSDL, getting the following error:

> “Syntax error on token , class expected ;
>   com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine cannot be resolved to a type”

For the below lines:

```
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Style.WRAPPED
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum.Use.LITERAL
```

When we manually changed the class path like below it compiled in 1.6:

```
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Style.WRAPPED
com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype.Use.LITERAL
```

I have tried many option but couldn't find the proper solution. I have also posted the problem in other forum but looks like no solution so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution to my question by myself, though it took long time, so here is the solution.

1. change `com.ibm.ws.webservice.engine.enum` to `com.ibm.ws.webservice.engine.enumtype`
2. add `"com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_7.0.0.jar"` to your classpath and recompile the code.

You can find the "com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_7.0.0.jar" in your `<WAS HOME>/runtimes`  folder

Answer (score 2):

Changing the package structure seems inevitable since enum is a keyword from Java5 onwards.
I have faced a similar issue when I converted a project from Java 1.4 to 1.5

Comment: how did you to that .... because I am still finding the solution for that ... could you help me with that

Comment: Mine was a more of manual effort. Modern IDEs could help you with the refactoring step. You can probably use an ANT script as well to do a global replace. http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: Mine wasn't the exact issue that you are facing. So for you I suppose you need to replace `com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enum` with `com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.enumtype`